# How do you suggest unique usernames to user in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say the username someone wants is taken, then I want the system to suggest a list of available usernames, say 5 suggestions.

Now, I can generate several usernames based on permutations and combinations of data I already have, like their name, birthday, e.t.c. But how do I make sure those generated usernames are available? I mean, if for each generated username, I have to query the database to check availability, in the worst case scenario this might become something like an infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: To check availability, you can use ONE query for all usernames you generate.

Comment: what if among the 5, 1 is unavailable, I have to check again, and if it is again unavailable the process becomes a loop.

Also, in this case, how am I supposed to detect exactly which one failed?

Comment: @aoi: Do you want to check again in case it becomes available? How often do you remove users?

Comment: @Vicario I am not checking again if the same name is available at that point of time. If a username is unavailable once, that means someone has taken it and doesn't matter if that person still exists. I will have to force the user to select a different username. Also, in my system, I am not actually removing users ever, there's just a flag being set to mark them as deleted, but that is a separate thing from this. Just assume, I need to be sure the username I generated or regenerated shouldn't already exist in the db, at the point of time when I am running the query

Comment: How can you fall in an infinite loop with a finite db? I guess your worst case (meaning really, really unlucky) is a loop over your whole data base. Still, you will be looping over only related usernames...

Comment: even with a finite db, if in the worst case, the system keeps generating and checking usernames which already exists, and hence repeat this process again and again...the situation becomes similar to an infinite loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the question is a base one so I'll provide a simple example:

```
<?php

// Untested code and only one of the many possible ideas
$suggestions = array(
    'foobar' => TRUE,
    'foo1974' => TRUE,
    'foo37' => TRUE,
    'drfoo' => TRUE,
    'mrfoo' => TRUE,
);


$params = $placeholders = array();
foreach(array_keys($suggestions) as $position => $username){
    $params['u' . $position] = $username;
    $placeholders[] = ':u' . $position;
}
$sql = 'SELECT username
    FROM user
    WHERE username IN (' . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';

$res = $conn->prepare($sql);
$res->execute($params);
while( $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    $suggestions[ $row['username'] ] = FALSE;
}


foreach($suggestions as $username => $available){
    if($available){
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The only way to provide an infinite list of available names is to use a very simple rule such as adding a consecutive number. In such case, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT username
FROM user
WHERE username REGEXP '^foo[0-9]+'
```

... and then:

```
$username = 'foo';

$suggestions = array();
$count = 0;
$names_left = 5;
while($names_left>0){
    $count++;

    if( !in_array($username . $count, $names_taken) ){
        $suggestions[] = $username . $count;
        $names_left--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are just checking for those usernames in the list which are not already taken. But what if 1 of them or all of them are taken? I will have to repeat this whole process over and over and over and over....again, that's what I am trying to avoid somehow

Comment: @aoi - I've updated my answer. I hope I've finally got what you have in mind.

Comment: You could also combine both methods - first try some suggestions, and if they exist try to add numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw up a list of ones to try (say a list of 15-20). Any hits present the first 5 to the user. Otherwise just say that there are no suggestions.

Possible cominations could include the ordering or surname, first name, initials, age, year of birth or just a random number. You should be at least possibly find at least one suggestion.

Comment: Your suggestion is good, but your solution here, in the worst case scenario is "no suggestions available". While I want to display atleast 5 at any given time.